# Angular 2 how to force locale

Tags: angular

I wrote some small app using Angular2 and used the [currency pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-class.html).
The currency formatted according my to browser`s language, can i somehow override that?

Answer (score -1):

Yep currency pipe allows you to put in the currency code, check the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-class.html)

Comment: I don`t want to put the symbol, because its not solved the locale problem. I want to change somehow the locale, so the numbers will be formatted according to the locale and the currency symbol will appear at the right place (in my case it should appear on the right side of the digits). If I change the symbol it not formats the digits and not putting the symbol at the correct place.